# Setting mouse pointer to position in another form

Tags: c#, winforms

In my first form(form1). I use a mouseToStart() function to make the mouse pointer start at a particular location.

```
private void mouseToStart()
{
    Point startingPoint = panel1.Location;
    startingPoint.Offset(155, 376);
    Cursor.Position = PointToScreen(startingPoint);
}
```

I then launch a second form(form2). When a button is clicked in form2, I want it to close and the mouse to go back to the location specified by the mouseToStart() function in form1. This is however not happening. The mouse stays at the point where I have clicked on form2, and form2 closes.

Comment: Is form2 opened as a Modal Form?

Comment: Well then, if the problem is in the button code on form2, that is the code we need to see. Are you calling `Close()` before you set the `Cursor.Position`?

Answer (score 1):

```
Form1 myForm1; // Set it to your instance of Form1
Point startingPoint = myForm1.panel1.Location; // You have to make panel1 public
startingPoint.Offset(155, 376);
Cursor.Position = myForm1.PointToScreen(startingPoint);
```